# background-image and img tag for seo

Tags: html, css, seo

I need to use background-image property so i can use background-size while I also need to use the img tag for SEO-related purposes.
Will having the img tag with display:none; penalize the site for SEO-related purposes?

If it's so, what's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pure SEO questions are not programming related.

Answer (score -1):

Does the image contain text that search engines could use? If not - there is no problem, you could delete the image and only use background-image.

But if it does contain text, I would first try to make a nice background without text, and use a nice font and add real text on it. If it's seems hard, you could write the text and use display: none for it.

You would have better controller over a img's width and height than for a background image (with IE8 at least), so I don't see why you'd have to use background-image for this?

**Edit**

Oh, to answer your question. It's hard to say if display: none would harm SEO. It depends... probably not! Google wants us to display the same content for them as for real users and we should try to make this possible. However - it's kind of impossible sometimes. Maybe try to use HTML5 micro data for info that Google want but no user wanna see.